# How can i get records of single id data in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I applied the $match condition but the response is neither getting fitter nor getting an error.
I want fileted records where I pass the page_id and expectation all versions detailed as those mapped with the passed page_id.

Here is my code
version model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const versionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    version_name: { type: String, required: true },
    version_slug: { type: String, required: true },
    is_active: { type: Boolean, required: true },
    is_deleted: { type: Boolean, required: true }
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("version", versionSchema);
```

pages version model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const pageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    page_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'pages', require: true }, 
    version_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'versions', require: true },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("pageVersion", pageSchema);
```

controller

```
pageversions.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: "versions",
                localField:"version_id",
                foreignField:"_id",
                as: "version"
            }
        },
        { $unwind: "$version" },
        {
            $project: {
                page_id:1,
                version_name: "$version.version_name",
                virsion_slug: "$version.version_slug",
                is_active: "$version.is_active"
            }
        }
    ]);
};
```

getting response

```
[
  {
    "_id": "64b77c1f2712e47f8211aae2",
    "page_id": "64b77c1f2712e47f8211aae0",
    "version_name": "V2",
    "virsion_slug": "v2",
    "is_active": true
  },
  {
    "_id": "64b78219a56c70b185045f7b",
    "page_id": "64b77c1f2712e47f8211aae0",
    "version_name": "V1",
    "virsion_slug": "v1",
    "is_active": true
  },
  {
    "_id": "64b786251a4b4aa03e869adb",
    "page_id": "64b786251a4b4aa03e869ad9",
    "version_name": "V1",
    "virsion_slug": "v1",
    "is_active": true
  }
]
```

Expected Response

```
[
  {
    "_id": "64b77c1f2712e47f8211aae2",
    "page_id": "64b77c1f2712e47f8211aae0",
    "version_name": "V2",
    "virsion_slug": "v2",
    "is_active": true
  },
  {
    "_id": "64b78219a56c70b185045f7b",
    "page_id": "64b77c1f2712e47f8211aae0",
    "version_name": "V1",
    "virsion_slug": "v1",
    "is_active": true
  }
]
```

I want all version names whose page_id value is "64b77c1f2712e47f8211aae0"

I'm new to Node
kindly help.

here is collection details

collection: pageversions

[image: collection: pageversions]

collections:versions

[image: collections:versions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter the results by `page_id`, you should add a `$match` stage at the beginning of the `aggregate` function.

Try

```
pageversions.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            page_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("64b77c1f2712e47f8211aae0")
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "versions",
            localField:"version_id",
            foreignField:"_id",
            as: "version"
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$version" },
    {
        $project: {
            page_id:1,
            version_name: "$version.version_name",
            virsion_slug: "$version.version_slug",
            is_active: "$version.is_active"
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: I tried this too but got an error @Abdull

TypeError: Class constructor ObjectId cannot be invoked without 'new'

Comment: @pradeep_spidy Then try `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("64b77c1f2712e47f8211aae0")`